# Comparação entre dois Arrays

Tags: javascript, filtro

Possui dois arrays "todasDisciplinas" e "lancamentos" e gostaria de formar um terceiro com as disciplinas que ainda não foram lançando "pendentesDisciplinas".

```
this.lancamentos 0: {
    alunoId: 71, 
    disciplina: "Algebra Linear" 
} 

this.todasDisciplinas 
0: { 
    alunoId: 71, 
    disciplina: "Sistemas Distribuidos" 
    }, 
1: { 
    alunoId: 71, 
    disciplina: "Algebra Linear" 
}
```

Gostaria de percorrer os dois arrays e carregar somente o que possui de diferente entre os dois, exemplo:

```
this.pendentesDisciplinas 0: { 
    alunoId: 71, 
    disciplina: "Sistemas Distribuidos" 
}
```

Umas das formas que tentei implementar foi a utilização do `.filtrer` porém acredito que possa ter algo incorreto.

```
for (var x = 0; x < this.lancamentos.length; x++){
   this.pendentesDisciplinas = this
    .todasDisciplinas
        .filter(discPend => discPend.disciplina 
            != this.lancamentos[x].disciplina);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Recebi todas as disciplinas no array "pendentesDisciplinas"

```
this.pendentesDisciplinas = (dados.data as Disciplina[])
```

Após percorri os dois outros arrays coloquei uma condição de igualdade e caso aquela disciplina possua nos dois arrays efetuo o delete do "pendentesDisciplinas"

```
for(var x = 0; x < this.lancamentos.length; x++)
{ 
  for(var y = 0; y < this.todasDisciplinas.length; y++)
  { 
    if(this.todasDisciplinas[y].disciplina == this.lancamentos[x].disciplina && 
       this.todasDisciplinas[y].alunoId == this.lancamentos[x].alunoId)
    { 
        delete(this.pendentesDisciplinas[y]); 
    }
  }
}
```